# Adaptar código ao fragment

Tags: java, android

Bom dia tinha postado a duvida mas tentei agora simplificar para ser mais simples a ajuda espero que me possam ajudar. Eu estou a usar o googleplaces e quando escrevo em uma editText recebo sugestões de locais em recyclerView, eu segui um tutorial para fazer isto em uma activity  e está a funcionar mas agora preciso de adaptar o código a uma fragment .

As coisas que eu não sei se estou a fazer correcto é o seguinte no código da activity aparece para meter **this** e eu coloquei no fragment GetActivity().GetAppContext() para tentar adaptar o código e assim substituir não dá erro mas não sei se é correcto.

O erro também pode tar associado com um contructor que fui obrigado a criar no RecyclerListener ou talvez no Adapter

Eu não sei se é correcto passar assim para o adapter

```
 mAutoCompleteAdapter =  new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.searchview_adapter,
            mGoogleApiClient, BOUNDS_INDIA, null);
```

**O código do adapter é este :**

```
public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int resource, GoogleApiClient googleApiClient,
                                LatLngBounds bounds, AutocompleteFilter filter) {
    mContext = context;
    layout = resource;
    mGoogleApiClient = googleApiClient;
    mBounds = bounds;
    mPlaceFilter = filter;
}
```

**Fui obrigado a criar este contructor no ReclyclerListener :**

```
 public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Tenho embaixo o resto do código e está la o contructor que uso para a activity e funciona na activity agora precisava de criar um novo contructor para funcionar no fragment e a minha tentativa não sei se teve sucesso.

**O código do meu Reclycler Listener :**

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }


    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }



    public RecyclerItemClickListener(PlacesAutoCompleteActivity context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

@Override public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildLayoutPosition(childView));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { }

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}
```

}

**O código do meu fragment1 :**

```
import com.example.hp.tumg13.R;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements
         GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener  {
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_INDIA = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(-0, 0), new LatLng(0, 0));

    private EditText mAutocompleteView;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
    private LinearLayout ll;
    private PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter mAutoCompleteAdapter;
    ImageView delete;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null){
            return null;
        }
      LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragement1_layout, container, false);
        mRecyclerView= (RecyclerView) ll.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        mAutocompleteView = (EditText)ll.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_places);
        delete=(ImageView)ll.findViewById(R.id.cross);


        mAutoCompleteAdapter =  new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.searchview_adapter,
                mGoogleApiClient, BOUNDS_INDIA, null);



        mLinearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mRecyclerView.getContext()));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAutoCompleteAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        delete.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) getActivity());
        mAutocompleteView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                      int count) {
                if (!s.toString().equals("") && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    mAutoCompleteAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                } else if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Constants.API_NOT_CONNECTED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e(Constants.PlacesTag, Constants.API_NOT_CONNECTED);
                }

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                        final PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mAutoCompleteAdapter.getItem(position);
                        final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
                        mAutocompleteView.setText(item.description);

                        Log.i("TAG", "Autocomplete item selected: " + item.description);
                        /*
                             Issue a request to the Places Geo Data API to retrieve a Place object with additional details about the place.
                         */
                        PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                                .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
                        placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                                if (places.getCount() == 1) {
                                    //Do the things here on Click.....
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(places.get(0).getLatLng()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Constants.SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        Log.i("TAG", "Clicked: " + item.description);
                        Log.i("TAG", "Called getPlaceById to get Place details for " + item.placeId);
                    }
                })
        );



    return (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragement1_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks((GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) getActivity())
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener((GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) getActivity())
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .build();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v==delete){
            mAutocompleteView.setText("");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é o erro que dá quando substitui `this` por `getActivity()`?

Comment: Não dá erro só não se pode influenciar o facto de eu não estar a receber qualquer tipo de sugestões de localização